# Smart searching in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, http

I recently saw a person do a search on his web browser. He was searching on his company's website. If I wanted to do a search on his company's website, I would usually go to the company website, and enter the search string in the search box on the website. Instead, he simply opened up Chrome, and entered a couple of letters in his browser's address bar, eg. "myc", and Chrome immediately identified that he wanted to search the company website. He, then entered the search string and Chrome searched the company website using that string. 
Can someone tell me how must he have done this? I was digging around Chrome, and I saw that it maintains a list of search engines, I guess he must have added the company search to this list, but how does one invoke it like he did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like they added a [custom search engine](http://www.minterest.org/how-to-create-custom-search-engines-google-chrome/). Find the query URL of the site you want, replace the query string with %s, then save it as a new search engine with whatever keyword you want ("myc" in your example).

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I was searching the web in stone-age fashion all this long.